# Creating database using sql script and sqlserverdbconnection class gives error ["Failed to connect to server"]

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, security

```
SqlServerDBConnection.SqlServerDBConnection objDB = new   SqlServerDBConnection.SqlServerDBConnection();

string s = SqlServerDBConnection.SqlServerDBConnection.ConnStr;
bool isDBCreated = objDB.CheckAndCreateDatabase(txtSrvName.Text.ToString(), txtUid.Text.ToString(), txtPwd.Text.ToString(), txtDB.Text.ToString());
```

Above is the code which is being used to connect , create database using script.
Above code runs awesome on local but when I deployed on client side it shows

> "Failed to connect to server".

SqlConnection is working fine.
Sql server is connecting database to server.
Is there any code issue or security issue?

Comment: more detail are needed. what's the environment? sql and app are on different machines? which protocl is specified in the connection string? windows authentication or sql authentication? you can connect to the server with other tools (eg: ssms)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there's enough information in the question to resolve the issue but some ideas:

1. Check if firewall is allowing connections on TCP 1433.

To test it you can simply telnet the server from outside the network to simulate your client's conneciton:
    telnet {SERVER_IP} 1433

If you can't connect, check out this document: [Configure the Windows Firewall to Allow SQL Server Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc646023.aspx)

2. Make sure SQL Server is set to accept remote connections

In SSMS, right click on the server name and select Properties. In Connections section make sure "Allow remote connections to this server" is checked.

Having that said, I wouldn't recommend connecting to database directly from the client site. A better approach would be putting a web API in front of the database and let the API handle database operations. Since the data will be transmitted over HTTP/HTTPS firewall configurations and network access wouldn't be an issue. But it's just a long-term solution obviously.

Hope this helps a bit.